# Change punctuation of lists in r?

Tags: r

For text, I can change the punctuations. But I have a list like this.

```
df<- structure(list(`d/1` = structure(list(lists..1.. = c(43L, 64L, 
55L, 52L, 56L, 68L, 33L, 15L, 10L, 62L, 3L, 51L, 16L, 80L, 48L, 
6L, 58L, 38L, 91L, 76L, 95L, 32L, 17L, 45L)), .Names = "lists..1..", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), class = "data.frame"), `d/2` = structure(list(lists..2.. = c(100L, 
67L, 84L, 93L, 8L, 22L, 38L, 71L, 76L, 99L, 31L, 18L, 5L, 48L, 
25L, 68L, 94L, 81L, 36L, 45L, 56L, 34L, 74L, 44L)), .Names = "lists..2..", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("d/1", "d/2"))
```

As shown, data involves dataframes which have `/` in their name. I change `/` to `-` .
So as a result, I want to see `d-1` and `d-2` under `df`

Comment: Your df is a list, not a dataframe.

Comment: It's same like text.`names(df) <- gsub("/", "-", names(df))`